# I removed the "wp_rm_logs" table and am constantly getting this error

Tags: wp-query, database, errors

> [12-Sep-2017 11:00:55 UTC] require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, wps_rm_rules::is_404,
>   wps_rm::write_log created by INSERT INTO wp_rm_log (source, target,
>   code, timestamp, user_referral, user_agent, user_ip) 
>                              VALUES ('/wp-content/uploads/filename.jpg', 'Default WordPress 404 Error', '404', '2017-09-12 14:00:55', '',
>   'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
>   '164.132.216.252') for this query WordPress database error Table
>   'sitename_wp.wpi_rm_log' doesn't exist

How can I fix this error?

When I installed WordPress, this table doesn't exist. It came after I started using it a little. After I had a log, I thought it was insignificant and I removed it.

What is wp_rm_logs?

Comment: You must have a plugin that was using it. Don't go around deleting tables if you don't understand what they do. The table includes `rm` in the name. Do you have any plugins whose acronym might be "RM"?

Comment: @cjbj you're right. This plugin is Easy **R**edirect **M**anager.